# How to use expandos in backtick shell command

Tags: mutt

In my `.muttrc` I have `attribution` set to emulate Outlook-style message quoting like this:

```
set attribution="\n\n-----Original Message-----\nFrom: %f\nSent: %d\n%t\nSubject: %s\n"
```

However, the `%t` expando evaluates to "To Persons_Name" with no colon after the "To" so I'd like to run it through a shell command to add the colon. I can use backticks to run a shell command but I can't figure out how to get the value of the `%t` expando in the shell command. I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
set attribution="\n\n-----Original Message-----\nFrom: %f\nSent: %d\n`echo %t | sed s/^To/To:/`\nSubject: %s\n"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell commands are executed when the config setting is read, not every time you reply. You can see that by entering

```
 set attribution="Date: `date`"
```

It never changes. And of course, expandos aren't expanded at that moment.

There is way: if you end the string with a `|`, mutt assumes it is a command and just executes it and uses its output (the documentation says it *pipes* the arguments through the first word, but that's a lie).

The problem is, there isn't any unix command (that I know of) which applies a regex to its arguments and outputs the result. `sed`, for instance, only works on files or stdin.

You have to create that command yourself. In Perl, it would be something like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $regexp = shift;
my @out;
for (@ARGV) {
  eval $regexp;
  push @out, $_;
}

print join " ", @out;
```

Let's say you put this in your path and name it `r.pl` (remember to chmod-x it), then you can set your attribution this way:

```
set attribution="r.pl 's/^To /To: /m' 'From: %n\n%t\netc...\n'|"
```

Take a look into `man perlre` to find out why you need to end the regexp with `/m`.

HTH.

Comment: This is great. I got it into an (ugly) one-liner like this: `set attribution="perl -e \'$_=shift;s/^To /To: /m;print;\' \"\n\n-----Original Message-----\nFrom: %f\nSent: %d\n%t\nSubject: %s\"|"`. Only problem is it seems to eat any trailing whitespace so I can't get a blank line before the message body, but I can live with that.